# Grabcut OpenCV Android Error in Output Image

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am using OpenCV with Android and performing Grabcut on an image for foreground extraction, I am getting the output as expected but the output image has a blue tone and not as the original image that was provided? What is the solution to the problem?

I am attaching the code that I am using currently for the same.

```
private Mat performGrabCut(Mat image)
{
      Mat firstMask = new Mat();
      Mat foregroundModel = new Mat();
      Mat backgroundModel = new Mat();

      Mat mask;

      Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(3.0));
      Mat destination = new Mat();

      Rect rect = new Rect(topLeft, bottomRight);

      Imgproc.grabCut(image, firstMask, rect, backgroundModel, foregroundModel, 1, 0);

      Core.compare(firstMask, source, firstMask, Core.CMP_EQ);

      Mat foreground = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255,255,255));
      image.copyTo(foreground, firstMask);
      return foreground;
}
```

Comment: You probably have an issue with channel order, OpenCV uses BGR by order whereas other libs generally use RGB.

Comment: how can this be done in android ?

Comment: use OpenCV's cvt color with `Imgproc.cvtColor(src, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);`

Comment: @y300 thanks. your solution did the trick

Comment: Solution to your problem is given
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076708/opencv4android-grabcuts-output-image-has-different-colorsbrighter-colors-than"> here</a>
in similar question.